# Bootstrap Modal form appearing just in my local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My modal form won't appear in my web-site.
When i launch it in my localhost, appear and no problem, but in my website, i have 2 problem 
1- don't appear
2- all the page under the place of this modal form is inaccessible.

My page has this source code :

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                  {{  prime.primeponctUtil ? 'Modifier affectation'  : 'Affecter la prime à un TA'}}

                              </button>

                              <!-- Modal -->
                              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">
                                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choisissez un TA</h4>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-body">
                                              <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                                  <thead>
                                                      <tr>
                                                          <th>Login</th>
                                                          <th>Nom</th>
                                                          <th>Prenom</th>
                                                      </tr>
                                                  </thead>
                                                  <tbody>
                                                      {% for util in utilisateurs %}
                                                          <tr>
                                                              <td><a href="{{ path('prime_affectation', {'myprime':prime.id , 'myutil':util.id }) }}" >{{  util.utilLogin }}</a></td>
                                                              <td>{{  util.utilNom }}</td>
                                                              <td>{{  util.utilPrenom }}</td>                                                         
                                                          </tr>
                                                      {% endfor %}
                                                  </tbody>
                                              </table>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
```

Comment: It might be a jQuery inclusion issue.

Comment: In most browsers you can get lots of debugging information by pressing F12. You'll probably find that it's failing to load bootstrap or something related. Maybe you forgot to change the URL to an actual URL instead of a file on your computer :-) Or maybe it's something more subtle like CORS (i.e. authorising scripts to access things on other domains).

Comment: I use Symfony2 framework and the urls are automaticly rewritting

Comment: (I don't know what Symfony2 is.) You mean the URLs are loading successfully? Are there any error messages?